# Call previously completed responses in a form whit a code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Call previously completed responses in a form with a code.
I am trying to create a form that can call previously completed responses through of a code previously completed. Is that possible with regular google forms tools? There is an extension which one that permit to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `getResponse(responseId)`, `getResponses()` and `getResponses(timestamp)`, there is no need of using an add-on. Anyway you can find the available add-ons on the Google Workspace Marketplace or from a Google Form.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponseresponseid
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponsestimestamp
- [Use add-ons, Apps Script & AppSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)